# HTML Toggle Menu Disappearing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have created a simple HTML menu and applied some media queries to it. I am using a Menu Hook, clicking on which brings the menu on small devices with the slideToggle in jquery. When we toggle the menu on small screen to visible and maximize the screen it works all fine, but if we toggle to hide the menu and maximize the screen with hidden menu it disappears. You can check by resizing the window in and toggling the menu. Below is the jquery I am using to toggle the menu.

```
$(function(){
    $("#toggle").click(function(){
        $(".t-m").slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
```

Here is the link to the code
http://codepen.io/SurajVerma/pen/thEKp.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achive this by using javascript `window.innerWidth` with the help of `window.onresize = function(event){...}`...

```
window.onresize = function(){

   if(window.innerWidth > 641){
     $(".t-m").slideDown("fast"); // show .t-m when screen size is > 641

   }
   if(window.innerWidth <= 640){
     $(".t-m").slideUp("fast"); // hide .t-m when screen size is <= 640
   }

}
```

EDITED:

See it [here...](http://jsfiddle.net/3d326/)

Note: don't resize your browser, just the window inside the page.

Comment: If you noticed that the second **if statement** hides the `.t-m` whenever you resize your window from widest to narrow or vice versa. If you don't want that just delete it. The first **if statement** solved your problem anyways.

Comment: I am not able to see the jsfiddle, can you check the link please. Thanks.

Comment: I think they are fixing their site. Try it here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vtlCr

Answer (score 0):

I think your CSS is causing this unexpected behaviour. It is assumed that the `Menu` element is always visible on the screen.

I have modified your css properties as follows and it works for me.

```
#toggle{
    float: right;
    display: inline;
}

.t-m{
    float: right;
    display: none;
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your response, Menu element should be visible only on small devices, as the media query says [@media all and (max-width: 640px) and (min-width: 320px)] and clicking on it will toggle the main menu from visible and hidden. If I am missing any point please correct me.

Answer (score 0):

see  [this](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp). It says that - (dash) is a css selector so your .t-m means that it is sliding `m` element which is preceeds by .t class. Change the class name with only alphabets in it like this : **.tm**

Comment: @sri nope, Actually the codepen I shared, is just a demo of the issue, I am doing it in a mega menu with proper classes, in that also, it is not working.